# sync.Mutex or http.HandleFunc not working

Tags: go, webserver, mutex, goroutine

I am using the textbook: "The Go Programming Language" and in it they show how to make a webserver using Go.

Following the code they give, I made a webserver:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
)

var mu sync.Mutex
var count int

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.HandleFunc("/count", counter)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8080", nil))
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    mu.Lock()
    count++
    mu.Unlock()
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "URL.Path = %q\n", r.URL.Path)
}

func counter(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    mu.Lock()
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Count %d\n", count)
    mu.Unlock()
}
```

Afterwards I wanted to test my knowledge with goroutines so I made a program that will call the server endpoint: "/rest" 1000 times.

Then I call the endpoint: "/count" which is suppose to return the amount of times the previous endpoint was called.

`send.go`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {
    times, _ := strconv.Atoi(os.Args[1])
    
    for i := 0; i < times; i++ {
        go call()
    }

    response, err := http.Get("http://localhost:8080/count")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ERROR ", err)
    }
    
    text, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    fmt.Println(string(text))
    response.Body.Close()
}

func call() {
    _, _= http.Get("http://localhost:8080/rest")
}
```

The problem is this: the /count endpoint returns a number less than 1000. Please tell me what I am doing wrong, or if there is I'm misunderstanding about how sync.Mutex or http.HandleFunc() works.

Comment: Thank you, I tried using `sync.WaitGroup` and it all worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mutex only ensures that no two goroutines will write/read `count` at the same time, *however* it does not control the order in which those goroutines are executed.

That means that there is nothing in your code that ensures that all of the `go call()` are finished before `http.Get(".../count")` is executed.

If you want to execute `http.Get(".../count")` only *after* all of the `go call()` are finished, then you can do that by using a [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://pkg.go.dev/sync@go1.17#WaitGroup).

Answer (score 0):

`sync.Mutex` and `http.HandleFunc` are working as they should, but every handler is run in it's own go-routine.  There is no guarantee that *any* call to `handler` is run before the call to `count` irrespective of the order they are posted to the server.

In your test program you can remove the `go` keyword before `call()` which will ensure that all the requests are run in series, since `Get()` waits for a return from the server.  Or you could use the `WaitGroup` as suggested in the comments which would allow the requests to be processed in parallel but wait for them all to finish before sending the count request.